# How to select the closest descendant using jquery or selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get the descendant of a node that match **class="foo"**.
The problem is : I don't know how deep this descendant will be.
I know I could get the immediate child using >
Or if I knew how deep it is, I could use multiple > > > >
I could just use **class="foo"** but then I'll get descendant of my target that also match **class="foo"**.

**Is div.class="foo":first-child the solution ?**

```
div id="im_here"
  div id="child"
    ......
         div class="foo"              <= I want this
           ......
                div class="foo"       <= not that
                ......
                      div class="foo" <= not that
                      ......
```

Comment: I'm thinking that CSS alone won't do this. You're probably going to need JavaScript

Comment: in jquery you can use `$(".foo:first")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery's `:first` selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector) in conjunction with [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find):

```js
$('#im_here').find('.foo:first')
```